# Must basis vectors in a column vector be unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying Linear Algebra and have come to think of a column vector as an ordered bunch of objects, where each object is the product of a scalar and a basis vector, vis:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\vdots \\
\end{bmatrix} = a \hat{i} + b \hat{j} + \dots$

Where $a$ and $b$ are scalars and $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are *unique* basis vectors. By that I mean $\hat{i}$ must not equal $\hat{j}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Usually, the entries in a column vector are taken to be scalars, not vectors. The column vector $$\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr c\cr}$$ can be thought of as $ai+bj+ck$ where $i,j,k$ are basis vectors for some vector space.

Comment: If $\hat i=\hat j$, then $(1)\hat i+(-1)\hat j=\vec0$, which contradicts linear independence of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. A basis is supposed to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not exactly correct. The entries in a column vector come from a linear combination of the basis vectors.

This would be the case if you use the basis vectors $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$ The entries of a vector written as a linear combination of these these vectors would be a scalar multiple of the basis vectors.

Whereas in a basis like $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}  $$ There are vectors whose entries come from a the sum of the scalar multiples of both vectors. Such as $$2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+ 3\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}9 \\ 12 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}11 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, basis vectors are linearly independent, so they better be unique, or else they're not basis vectors.

To clarify Seeker's answer:

> The entries in a column vector come from a linear combination of the basis vectors.

This is referring to all entries at once, i.e. the whole resultant column vector. A linear combination of (basis) vectors will obviously produce a vector. For example using the unit basis vectors:

$$
a\hat{i} + b\hat{j} = a\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}
$$

Each *element* in a vector is a linear combination of certain *elements* in the basis vectors. For example $a=a(1)+b(0)$.

What you said is true if $\hat{i}, \hat{j}, ...$ are simple unit basis vectors e.g. $(1,0,...), (0,1,...), ...$. But it's not necessarily true for other basis vectors (as Seeker said).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you.

That really leads well into the question I was wanting to get at: given a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & d \\
b & e \\
c & f \\
\end{bmatrix}$

both column vectors have to be written with the same ordering of basis vectors, right? If $a$ is scaling $\hat{i}$ then $d$ must also be scaling $\hat{i}$?

Comment: Past-the-five-minute-mark edit:

I blooped this as a proper question here: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4621491/170148

Answer (score 0):

@mr_e_man got it:

> If $\hat{i} = \hat{j}$, then $(1) \hat{i} + (−1) \hat{j} = 0$, which contradicts linear independence of $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$. A basis is supposed to be linearly independent.

Vectors must come from vector spaces, vector spaces must have basis, and basis must be linearly independent. So, each component in a column vector must correspond to a unique basis.