# Must all column vectors in a matrix be written with the same ordering?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & d \\
b & e \\
c & f \\
\end{bmatrix}$
, both column vectors have to be written with the same ordering of basis vectors, right? In other words, if $a$ is scaling $\hat{i}$ then $d$ must also be scaling $\hat{i}$?

Comment: The question makes no sense.

Comment: Yes. Using matrix multiplication to evaluate a linear transformation implicitly adds together vectors represented as ordered n-tuples. If they are represented using different ordered bases then you can't add them component by component - at least not sensibly.

Comment: You've made four posts for what is essentially the same question? I haven't read them all deeply, so i might be missing something, but if that's what you did, please don't do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621474/must-the-unit-vectors-implied-by-a-row-vector-be-unique/4621494#4621494) but yes, order is maintained. The elements in the top row correspond to linear combinations of the top elements of the basis vectors ("top" assuming by convention that the basis vectors are column vectors).